# Nested Vue Subroutes don't load automatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have an application with a sidebar.
As a default, when loading `patient/:id` I want to load the the `Patient` view, which on default should also load its sub-view `PatientDashboard`.

Inside the Patient view component, I have a router-view which should on default load the `PatientDashboard`-component.

However, every time I load the page to the route `patient/:id` I need to switch back and forth between teh sidebar buttons of `PatientDashboard` and `Timeline` to get my `PatientDashboard`-Component loaded.

So how do I get the default subroute to load the component on it's first load?

Patient-Component:

```
<template>
  <div">
    <ProfileSidebar :sidebar_elements="sidebar_elements"/>
    <div id="profile_content">
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Router:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: "/patient/:patient",
    name: "Patient",
    component: Patient,
    props: true,
      children: [
        {
          path: "timeline",
          name: "Timeline",
          component: Timeline
        },
        {
          path: "",
          name: "PatientDashboard",
          component: PatientDashboard
        },
      ],

  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `redirect` to the main route solved it:

```js
redirect: {
  name: "PatientDashboard"
},
```